# How to populate Dynamic UITableview Inside dynamic UITableviewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to implement the dynamic `UITableView` inside dynamic `UITableviewcell` like the below screenshot. Also, all values are dynamic which is coming from the server.

[image]

Comment: Can just use view for each store then push it into stackview, don't need tableview

Comment: Thank for your reply. Here everything is dynamic so that only I used uitableview. If I use Stack View how it will repeat based upon values from server. Please can you explain?

Comment: Why does it matter? On new response from server just remove all view from stackView and create them again, use tableView inside tableView is fine but you probably will face difficulties calculating height (performance wise your app also have to redraw all the child tableView's cell coz they are on screen so I think it wont be different)

Answer (score 0):

> yes exactly you need inner tableview to do this.
>   first you have main tableview with card layout cell this should be dynamic cell height.
>   in this cell you have topview, inner tableview, bottom view all this view you can take fix height as your layout i see e.g top view is 80 height, bottom view is 80 height and tableview has dynamic height based on number of cell like cell height is 100 and you have total 3 cell so table height is 300 you need to make outlet of tableview height and update it programmatically.

hope this helps you!

Comment: I implemented already what you said above. But I am getting issue [Please refer the link about the issue] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303720/how-to-implement-dynamic-uitableview-inside-dynamic-uitableviewcell-in-swift

Comment: your getting multiple data in myorderlist array? try reloading tableview in listArray method after set data.

Comment: As you said I reloaded the UITableview. I am getting all the values but it is not populating to the UITableViewCell properly it is populating only one value. And while scrolling the main tableview the values are changing.

Comment: what is your default inner tableview height ? make it big and change it later

Comment: TableView height is correct only but values are not populating. only one value is populating remaining all cells are showing empty but the tableview cell is having a value.Please refer the image in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303720/how-to-implement-dynamic-uitableview-inside-dynamic-uitableviewcell-in-swift like how I am getting.

Comment: check filterarray its have all values where u populate this array ?

Comment: Yes I am getting all values but it is not populating to the tableviewcell that is my issue.